# How to create a Collisions var in the Back class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, var

Edit: I have now included a Player.as and a addchild

I've been trying to understand how to do this all day and again learned a lot in doing so. But I've come to a point that i need help.

**I know I have to do this:** create a Collisions var in the Back1 class.

Because the background called Back1 is the movieclip that contains the Collisions image

I found a good site or 2 that does a good job of explaining variables and classes but i still don't get how i should solve this problem

***Research after variables and classes:***

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3variables/

http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/1136/flash-game-dev-tip-1-creating-a-cross-game-communications-structure

the above problem results in the folowing error but i believe it is caused by not creating a Collisions var in the Back1 class

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Bumper(). expected: 2, value 0.

- at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop() at
  DocumentClass/onRequestStart()DocumentClass.as:64] at
  flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction() at
  flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent() at
  MenuScreen/onClickStart()MenuScreen.as:18]

  ```
  package 
   {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.events.*;
  import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
  import flash.ui.Keyboard;
  import flash.geom.Point;
  import Bumper;
  //import Back1;

  public class Test extends MovieClip
  {

      public var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
  public var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
  public var upBumping:Boolean = false;
  public var downBumping:Boolean = false;

  public var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30,-55);
  public var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30,-55);
  public var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,-120);
  public var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0,0);

  public var scrollX:Number = 0;
  public var scrollY:Number = 500;

  public var xSpeed:Number = 0;
  public var ySpeed:Number = 0;

  public var speedConstant:Number = 4;
  public var frictionConstant:Number = 0.9;
  public var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
  public var jumpConstant:Number = -35;
  public var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;

  public var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
  public var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

  public var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
  public var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

  public var currentLevel:int = 1;

  public var animationState:String = "idle";

  public var bulletList:Array = new Array();
  public var enemyList:Array = new Array();
  public var bumperList:Array = new Array();
   public var back1:Back1;
  public var collisions:Collisions;
  //public var back1:Collisions = new Collisions ;
   public var player:Player;

  public function Test()
  {
      addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  }

  public function init(e:Event):void
  {

      player = new Player(320, 360);
      back1 = new Back1();
      collisions = new Collisions();
      //back1.collisions = new Collisons();
            addBumpersToLevel1();
  }
  public function addBumpersToLevel1():void
  {
      addBumper(500, -115);
      addBumper(740, -115);
  }
          public function addPlayerTolevel1():void 
  {
      addPlayer(320, 360);
  }
  public function loop(e:Event):void
  {
      trace("back1.collisions "+back1.collisions);
                  trace("back1 "+back1);
                  trace("collisions "+collisions);
      if (back1.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
      {
  ```

just in case i've added Bumper.as

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Bumper extends MovieClip{
    public function Bumper(xLocation:int, yLocation:int) {
        // constructor code
        x = xLocation;
        y = yLocation;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumper);
    }

    public function bumper(e:Event):void{
        //code here
    }
}

}
```

Player.as

```
 package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Player extends MovieClip {

        public function Player(xLocation:int, yLocation:int) {
            // constructor code
            x = xLocation;
            y = yLocation;
           }



     //   public function removeSelf():void {
      //      trace("remove enemy");
       //     removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
       //     this.parent.removeChild(this);
       // }



 }
 }
```

the Back1.as file (note it's got to be instanced wrong)

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class Back1 extends MovieClip {
    //public var collisions:Back1;
           //what should i put here?
}
}
```

Comment: Error said you passed zero arguments to constructor of Bumper class. How do you create it?

Comment: i've added some public var that i had cut out to make it more transparant....for example....public var bumperList:Array = new Array();

Comment: i think it now has the missing code for bumper

Comment: It sounds like you might have a "Bumper" movie clip on the timeline, which is causing the public function Bumper() to run without an xLocation and yLocation.

Comment: no it's not on the timeline it's created with addchild. One of the problems was just solved by Serge but it still gives a problem for the line if (back1.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true)) the erorr it returns is a null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand completely what you mean.  The question is phrased strange.

I assume you want to achieve a collision between your background object (The Back class) and a player object?  I can't see from the code you have posted what the player object is since there is no such variable in your Test class.

To test a collision check between two objects use the following code:

```
if(someObject.hitTestObject(anotherObject))
```

Or in your case when using hitTestPoint:

```
if(back1.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y,true))
```

Then again I don't know from the code you have posted how the back1 class looks like.  If it extends a MovieClip or Sprite and you have a Player class that does the same (OR any DisplayObject) this should work.

This:
*Argument count mismatch on Bumper(). expected: 2, value 0.*

The error you get seems to come from another place not shown in your code.  I would assume you did not pass any parameters into the Bumper class' constructor.

Btw, is this a Flash IDE sample or some other program such as FlashDevelop or FlashBuilder?  If you are using the Flash IDE and are trying to attach code to a movie clip instance placed out on the scene I don't think its possible to pass parameters to it.  Sorry been a while since I've worked in the Flash IDE.

**EDIT:**

Here's some sample code:

```
//::  Change Back1 class to this

package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class Back1 extends MovieClip {
    public function Back1()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
}


//::  Then in your Main class (Or the Test class) add the following

var player:Player = new Player(25, 25);
var collidable:Back1 = new Back1();

addChild(player);
addChild(collidable);

//::  Goes in your loop/update
if (collidable.hitTestPoint(player.x, player.y, true))
{
    trace("HIT PLAYER");
}
```

How you apply the graphics to the Back1 class is up to you, I just drew a simple box.  It could be anything.

Comment: I want collision with the "Collisions" image inside of Back1 movieclip. You are proabably right about "attach code to a movie clip instance placed out on the scene" i'll try to do a addchild on the player thanks

Comment: ok i've changed it to create a player with addchild (please see edited first post) thanks to Serge it now gives the correct error code.

Comment: Is  the collisions object even defined and instantiated in the Back1 class?

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid but just to be clear: Do you mean a seprate Back1.as file or/with..   like this public var back1:Collisions = new Collisions ; or collisions:Back1 = new Back1

Comment: Well looking at your code you reference a collisions object in your back1 object so I would assume its there inside the Back1 class.  I just wanted to make sure you had it instantiated in the class so you can actually reference it that way.  Could be the reason it crashed.

Comment: how should i instiate it in the class Back1.as file? this is what i had inside the Back1.as file: var collisions:Back1;

Comment: maybe it's collisions:Back1 = new Back1 hmm

Comment: I'm confused you have an object collisions of the type Back1 inside your own Back1 class?  Isn't it of the type Collisions like the collisions object you have in your Test class?

Could you show me how the .as file for Back1 looks like?

Comment: ok it's posted below in the top post thanks for your continued help

Comment: Okay Jacques looking at your Back1 class code it doesn't make (for me) any sense for you to apply an object of itself inside the class.  And it is not instantiated.  It is NULL, unless you give it a reference at some later point.  But this would cause recursion.  Meaning if you create a Back1 object and itself creates a Back1 object that object will also create a Back1 object and it will go on forever and ever.

I am not sure of the reasoning behind this.  But I would advice you to get rid of it or rethink your structure.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for pointing me on that recursion. If only i could think of a way to create a collision between Player and Collisions with the "Collisions" image inside of Back1 movieclip. And to make it not be null

Comment: To be honest I don't think you want to do that.  To create a collision between your player object and an image I can write some code for you.  We should continue this in the chat.

Or on a second note check my first post, I edited a solution there.

Comment: Yep, sorry.  Take a look at my first post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22840/discussion-between-jacques-and-placeable)

Answer (score 0):

Set default parameters for Bumper class:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Bumper extends MovieClip{
        public function Bumper(xLocation:int = 0, yLocation:int = 0) {
            // constructor code
            x = xLocation;
            y = yLocation;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumper);
        }

        public function bumper(e:Event):void{
            //code here
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: this helped but now it gives the correct error. TypeError: Error #1009: it basicilly tells that the following line gives null..... if (back1.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x,player.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true)).....(Also i've added a addchild of Player and player.as file thanks to advice from another user)